# How to deploy programs on multiple machines

Tags: software-installation, deployment

I need to install a few programs on around 40 Kubuntu 13.04 machines, and would like to know what options I have to do it as efficiently as possible.

EDIT: I have the repositories already set and the machines are all identical clones, with no LDAP auth or centralized server.

Comment: mussh, pssh, puppet, chef, etc.

Comment: Is the software installed through `apt`? Do the 40 machines already have their OS installed? Do they all have access to the necessary repositories? Do you have passwordless ssh access to each machine?

Comment: You want any script for the same ?

Comment: @terdon Yes, yes, yes, no, but I have root access to each, so its a possibility.

Comment: @RahulPatil "any script for the same" can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @Dudemcman already mention in my answer, do you need any help with that ?

Answer (score 3):

Any configuration management software will do, that's what they are for, i would suggest to take look at chef. This is the blurb from their webpage:

> Chef is an automation platform that transforms infrastructure into
>   code. Stop thinking in terms of physical and virtual servers. With
>   Chef, your real asset is the code that brings those servers and the
>   services they provide to life. An automated infrastructure can
>   accelerate your time to market, help you manage scale and complexity,
>   and safeguard your systems.
>
> Whether your network is in the cloud, on-site, or a hybrid, Chef can
>   automate how you configure, deploy and scale your servers and
>   applications, whether you manage 5 servers, 5,000 servers or 500,000
>   servers. It's no wonder that Chef has been chosen by companies like
>   Facebook and Amazon for mission-critical challenges.

this video will help a lot:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UXh5EnFZrM

home page:
http://www.opscode.com/chef/

Comment: All of these solutions seem to talk about runninng the tasks on servers. Does this mean running the task *from* a server, or that it is only designed to be used on servers?

Comment: It actually means running on the server :)

Answer (score 2):

**For long term goal**

If you want automation tool that allows you to centralize management of the various *nix flavors running on your network and  manage every aspect of the configuration that you can,  then you can look at :

1. puppet
2. chef
3. cfengine3

**For short term goal**

If you want temporary solution for just to install some package through `apt-get` or `yum`, then you can use shell or perl, python script.

If you have already set password-less authentication then you can just use following script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Servers_list=/opt/servers_list
PackageName="package-name"

for Host in $(< $Servers_list )
do
    echo "Installing package on $Host"
    ssh "${Host}"  apt-get -y install "${PackageName}"

done
```

If you don't have password less authentication then you can use `expect` tool  or `paramiko` module in python.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand Rahul's very good answer, you can set up passwordless access to each of the machines easily enough using this approach:

1. install [`sshpass`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) on your local machine:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sshpass
   ```

   This will allow you to pass the password as a command line argument:

   ```
    sshpass -p '<password>' ssh user@server
   ```
2. Create an ssh key

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa
   ```

   You can simplify things by allowing an empty passphrase (the rest of this answer will assume you have done so, let me know if your security concerns prohibit this and I will modify accordingly).
3. Create a file with all the IPs you are interested in and their respective username and passwords, one per line:

   ```
   1.2.3.4 bob bobs_password
   11.22.33.44 hary harrys_password
   ```

   Now, use `sshpass` to copy your key files and --as long as you've used an empty passphrase-- allow passwordless access to all machines:

   ```
   while read ip user pass; do 
     sshpass -p "$pass" ssh ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $user@$ip;
   done < ips.txt
   ```
4. Now that you have passwordless access set up, install your software on each machine (this assumes that `$user` can run `apt-get`, basically that `$user` is `root`):

   ```
    while read ip user pass; do 
      ssh $user@$ip "apt-get install package; 
    done < ips.txt
   ```

Comment: +1 "Now that you have passwordless access set up..." install a configuration management tool on all your clients and don't look back :)